# File upload path not working in <a href="path" target="_blank"> element

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload, file-io, upload

I am trying to display a file using the a href="block".

I am using Spring MVC to upload a file.

Following is my upload Code for HTML :-

```
  <form method="POST" action ="uploadDocument.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Please select your resume to upload : (.pdf, .doc , .docx)<br/>
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" required/><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>     
  </form>
```

Following is the controller code:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadDocument.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile fileUpload,Model model,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{


    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    UserAccount userAccount = (UserAccount)session.getAttribute("user");


        String contentType = fileUpload.getContentType();

        String format="";
        if(contentType.contains("pdf") || contentType.contains("vnd") || contentType.contains("msword")){

            if(contentType.contains("pdf")){
                format=".pdf";

            }
            else if(contentType.contains("vnd")){
                format=".docx";

            }
            else if(contentType.contains("msword")){
                format = ".doc";
            }

            String fileName = userAccount.getUsername()+format;

            System.out.println(fileName);

            String path ="E:\\eclipse\\workspace\\Zingo_Project\\src\\main\\webapp\\fileupload\\";


            fileUpload.transferTo(new File(path+fileName)); 


            model.addAttribute(fileName);
            return "fileUploadSuccessfull";             

        }           
        return "uploadUserFailure";             
    }
```

I can see the file uploaded in the desired location.
When I try to access the file in fileUploadSuccessfull.jsp.

Following is my code of fileUploadSuccessfull.jsp.

```
File upload Successfull!<br/>
</br>

<a href="E:\New version\eclipse\workspace\Zingo_Project\src\main\webapp\fileupload\zingo.pdf" target="_blank">Click here to View the File</a>
```

When I click on the link I cannot view the file in new Window.

I have been stuck here for hours and I tried giving the

```
    href as "file:///E:/New%20version/eclipse/workspace/Zingo_Project/src/main/webapp/fileupload/zingo.pdf"
or
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/fileupload/zingo.pdf"
```

Kindly help me I have been stuck here for hours.

Thanks,
Zingo

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the `fileupload` folder is in the root of your web app (like www.yoursite.com/project/fileupload), why not just having a static href?

```
<a href="/project/fileupload/zingo.pdf" target="_blank">Click here to View the File</a>
```

Make sure you upload the file to the right dir:

```
String uploadDir = "/fileupload/"; // or "/~project/fileupload/"
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath(uploadDir);
```

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /fileupload/zingo.pdf

This is the error that I am getting

and the URL says http://localhost:8080/fileupload/zingo.pdf

Comment: 1. Sure your app has no subfolder like `localhost:8080/webapp/fileupload/zingo.pdf`? 2. Sure the pdf is in this folder? Can you open it within your OS?

Comment: The subfolder "fileupload" exists under webapp/ and that the file also exists I can open it in my OS in the desired folder.

Comment: What's the URL of your start page? `localhost:8080/webapp/`?

Comment: It is localhost:8080/project.

Comment: I tried that too even this is not working! I am getting  the same error HTTP Status 404 - /webapp/fileupload/pratik.pdf

http://localhost:8080/webapp/fileupload/pratik.pdf

Comment: Hmm... how is the file system absolute path to your images or stylesheets folder? E.g. `E:\New version\eclipse\workspace\Zingo_Project\src\main\webapp\images`?

Comment: The absolute path is :-

E:\New version\eclipse\workspace\Zingo_Project\src\main\webapp\fileupload

Comment: Maybe your src gets compiled and resides somewhere else in the file system. What does `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` say?

Comment: This is what I am getting

E:\New version\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Zingo_Project\

Comment: Well, that's your path. Either set `string path = "E:\New version\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wt‌​pwebapps\Zingo_Pratik_Project\fileupload\"` or see my updated answer.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you see the file now?

Comment: I have done target="_blank" in my anchor tag that means it should open in new tab window. When i click on my url nothing no new tab is opened and I cannot view the file.

Comment: Please show me the rendered `<a>` tag like you get in your browser.

Comment: <a href="E:/New%20version/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Zingo_Project/fileupload/zingo.pdf" target="_blank">

Comment: Please try `<a href="/project/fileupload/zingo.pdf">` instead, just to test. Did you change the upload path in your java code?

Comment: I tried your suggestion it did not make any difference i am again getting 404 error. I did not change the upload path.

Comment: Well than, sorry, I can't help any further. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...!